# How to prove a sequence diverges? $a_n^\infty,$ defined by $a_{n+1}=-1-a_n^{2},\qquad a_1=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

So I'm given a sequence $a_n^∞$ that is defined in a recursive formula as follows: 
$$a_{n+1}=-1-a_n^{2},\qquad a_1=1$$
and they're asking prove/disprove that this sequence converges, so I'm thinking it diverges because as you plug in numbers you go further into negative values. The question is how to disprove it.. like I want to try contradiction but I don't know how to contradict this.

Every help is appreciated!

Comment: sequence $(a_n)$ or series $ \sum a_n$ ?

Comment: im not so sure but i think sequence

Comment: Assume that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$, then make a contradiction. Hint: If a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent with limit $a$, then $a_{n+1}\rightarrow a$ and $a_n\rightarrow a$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @Serdar but how do i contradict?

Comment: @Nicole: double check sequence or series.  You can't do the problem until you understand it, and you can't understand it until you know all the words in the problem.

Comment: Try proving by induction that $a_n\le-2^{2^{n-2}}$, for $n\ge2$.

Comment: Putting this question on hold after it received so many interesting answers is ridiculous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b_n = -a_n$ for $n\ge 2$ and $b_1=1$.

Then $b_{n+1}=b^2_n+1 \ge 2b_n$, because $b_n^2-2b_n+1=(b_n-1)^2 \ge 0$.

Therefore, $b_n \ge 2^{n-1} b_1 = 2^{n-1}$ and so $a_n \le - 2^{n-1}$ and $a_n$ diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: How did you get the $2^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: @Nicole, $b_n \ge 2b_{n-1} \ge 2^2 b_{n-2} \ge \cdots$. Or use induction.

Comment: ah i see because $b_1$ = 1, also why did you start from n >= 2 ?

Comment: @Nicole, because I wanted $b_1 >0$.

Comment: why does it contradict it being positive? and how did you establish that ($b_n$-1)$^{2}$ >= 0 ?

Comment: @Nicole, $x^2\ge0$ for every $x$.

Comment: yes but why ($b_n$-1)$^{2}$ ?

Comment: because of $0\leq (b_n-1)^2=b_n^2-2b_n+1\Leftrightarrow 2b_n\leq b_n^2+1$. You get it? ;-)

Comment: you're welcome:-)

Answer (score 4):

$a_1$ is a real number, and it's clear from the recurrence $a_{n+1} = -1 - a_n^2$ that $a_n$ must be real for all $n$. Hence, if $a_n$ converges, it must converge to a real limit.

Suppose that $a_n$ does converge, say to a limit $L$. Taking limits of both sides of $a_{n+1} = -1 - a_n^2$, we obtain $L = -1 - L^2$, or equivalently $L^2 + L + 1 = 0$. You can easily check that this equation has no real solutions (the $b^2 - 4ac$ term in the quadratic formula is $1 - 4 = -3$), so $L$ is not real. This contradiction implies that $a_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Looks like we posted the same answer simultaneously. :-)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Ha, indeed we did! (+1)

Comment: That was my suggestion to Nicole. :-)

Comment: @Serdar Indeed, a good suggestion! But I do agree with Giuseppe Negro that this approach isn't quite as insightful as it doesn't tell us *why* the sequence fails to converge (it marches off monotonically to $-\infty$).

Answer (score 3):

I think that the "best" answers are those already given, as they imply explicit bounds on $a_n$ that quantify the *blow-up rate* of the sequence, that is, the speed at which it diverges to infinity.

(**EDIT** What follows in the gray box is exactly the same as Bungo's answer)

> However, there is another method of proof. Observe that the sequence $a_n$ is integer. Assume for a contradiction that $a_n\to x$. Since the sequence $a_n$ is integer, $x$ must be integer. Moreover, since $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$, we obtain for $x$ the equation 
>   $$
> x^2+x+1=0.$$ 
>   Completing the square this equation can be rewritten as $(x+\tfrac12)^2+\tfrac34=0$ so it cannot have any real solution, let alone an integer one. (Thank you Daniel Wainfleet for the suggestion). We have reached the desired contradiction.

**NOTE**. We did not really use the assumption that $a_n$ is integer, we only used that it is real. It is therefore the case that the given recurrence relation $a_{n+1}=-1-a_n^2$ does not produce convergent sequences whatever the initial condition $a_0\in\mathbb R$ is.

It is interesting to compare with the recurrence relation $a_{n+1}=1 - a_n^2$. This leads to the equation $x^2+x-1=0$, with roots $x_\pm=\tfrac12(-1\pm\sqrt 5)$. These roots are not integer, and consequently the sequence $a_n$ cannot converge if $a_0$ is integer; to prove this, just apply the argument above.

However, this argument does not say anything in the case of noninteger $a_0$. This is no coincidence, for in this case there do exist noninteger initial data such that $a_n$ converges: taking $a_0=x_+$ or $a_0=x_-$, where $x_\pm$ are the roots found above, yields two constant sequences, hence convergent.

> Changing a $+1$ to a $-1$ in the original recurrence produced a dramatic change in the behavior of the solutions.

Comment: In fact, the solutions are $\frac{1}{2}(-1 \pm \sqrt{-3})$, so they aren't even real.

Comment: You are right, I noticed it while reading your answer

Comment: I gave this  a +1 because the proposer did ask about a proof by contradiction.  For those unfamiliar with $\Bbb C$ it would suffice to  say that if $x$ exists then $x\in \Bbb R,$ but no $x\in \Bbb R$ can satisfy $0=x^2+x+1=(x+1/2)^2+3/4.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I incorporated your suggestion into the answer.

Comment: You call that "grey" ?  :-) .   Your  colorblindness just got outed!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft : hahaha I must admit that I am not exactly a hawk

Answer (score 1):

For convenience we can safely ignore the minus signs and consider

$$a_{n+1}=a^2_n+1.$$

It is obvious that

$$a_n\ge2\implies a_{n+1}=a_n^2+1>a^2_n\ge2a_n$$ so that the sequence is bounded below by a diverging geometric progression.

Comment: why is $a_n$ greater or equal 2 ? also what is a geometric progression?

Comment: @Nicole: read carefully. The sentence says "if $a_n\ge2$ then $a_{n+1}>2a_n$". Now establish the relation to your question.

Comment: @lhf: you skipped my first sentence, it seems.

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm very confused ):

Comment: youre saying define a new sequence and argue that it diverges and then apply it to $a_n$ ?

Comment: @lhf: no, the negatives will add confusion. And I chose $a_n\ge 2$ rather than $\ge1$ on purpose.

Comment: @Nicole: the minus signs are immaterial, thanks to the square.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why though because I dont seem to get it

Comment: @Nicole: have you learnt the proofs by induction ? This is a perfect example.

Comment: We have but were told not to apply it to this question

Comment: @Nicole: good luck then.